# I have just started making a basic interactive calculator in Python, but can't figure out why it won't accept the given input

Tags: python

```
num = input("Please enter one number to be added:")
num1 = input("Please enter another number to be added:")
num2 = input("Please enter the third number to be added (if no more numbers are required, type None:")
if num2 == "None" or "NONE" or "none" or "nOne":
    print("One moment please")
    print(num * num1)
else: 
    print("Maximum Numbers Reached")
```

Above is a sample of the code. The line with num * num1 is the one that has been giving me trouble. I've tried several different variations, including str, int, float, but they won't multiply (or add, subtract, etc...). I've changed everything from the input method to making numbers strings and vice versa. I've tried debugging(didn't work) but nothing makes sense. I made a separate file and ran this:

```
me = 2
me2 = 3
print(me + me2)
```

This adds me and me2 just fine. However, the original section just won't work. Is there something wrong here, or do I need to give my brain some recharge time...? Anyway, if you have any ideas, I would appreciate the help.
Thanks, Jerry

Comment: `num` and `num1` are string. You need to convert to int or float first. Also your `if` condition is wrong. It will always evaluate to True

Comment: That's not checking every possible combination of lower- and upper-case versions of `"none"`. It would be much easier to check `if num2.lower() == "none"`

Comment: That's not how you combine conditions using `or`.

Comment: A better way to check if input is the word "None", instead of `if num2 == "None" or "NONE" or "none" or "nOne":` use `if num2.lower() == "none"` this will check the lowercase string of the input against a lowercase "none" and so will return the right answer regardless of the input case. Also, in the original code, it will always return `True` because "NONE" by itself returns True when used as a boolean expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues in the code, refer to the modified code -

```
check = True # condition for invalid input
while check:
    try:
        num = int(input("Please enter one number to be added:")) # needs to be type int
        num1 = int(input("Please enter another number to be added:")) # needs to be type int

        # not a good approach to accept None inplace of a number
        num2 = int(input("Please enter the third number to be added (if no more numbers are required, Enter 0")) 
    
        check = False 
    except:
        print('Please enter only Integer values')

if not num2:
    print("One moment please")
    print(num + num1) # you are multiplying while saying taking numbers for addition? code has been edited here to addition '+'
else: 
    print("Maximum Numbers Reached")
```

Comment: if user does not enter any value, it will raise `ValueError` since you're basically trying to do `int("")`

Comment: Hi @yedpodtrzitko Agreed, albeit I was only trying to provide some guidance based on the question asked **not sure of what all constraints will be there**, we can go ahead and design the whole application for OP this way xD

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I have edited the code for OP, Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

you had a quite common beginner mistake!
basically what you did was instead of

```
variable = int(input(words))
```

you put

```
variable = input(words)
```

you need the int at the beginning or everything is seen as a string.

Answer (score -1):

When you are inputting numbers like this, the numbers are taken as strings not integers:

Try this:

```
num1 = int(input("Please enter one number to be added:"))
num2 = int(input("Please enter another number to be added:"))
choice = input("Please enter the third number to be added (if no more numbers are required, type None:").lower()
if choice == 'none':
    print("One moment please")
    print(num1 * num2)
else: 
    print("Maximum Numbers Reached")
```

Edit: If condition modified

Comment: If condition needs to be fixed too

Comment: Not fixed yet, it won't detect, for example `NoNE`.

Comment: Actually had edited the code but don't know why didn't reflect edited again. Sorry, new to the site.